# Print Any Value each time TextFormField Change

Tags: flutter, dart

So I want to show any output according to the Value is printed following the Text Inputted inside the textfield

### This is the TextFormField Code

```
SizedBox(
            width: 70.0.w,
            height: 5.0.h,
            child: Form(
              key: _pulsa,
              child: TextFormField(
                onChanged: Judul,
                controller: _pls,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Nomor Tujuan"),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                ],
              ),
            )),
```

### Judul() Functions

```
Judul(String value) {
  if (value == '1') {
    print('one');
  } else if (value == '2') {
    print('two');
  } else if (value == '3) {
    print('Three');
  } else if (value == '4') {
    print('Four');
  } else if (value == '5') {
    print('Five');
  } else if (value == '6') {
    print('Six');
  } else if (value == '7') {
    print('Seven');
  } else (value){
    print('null');
  };
  return;
}
```

### Where I call the Judul Functions

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
   child: Text(
   Judul('')
        )
      ),
```

### Text Widget Part

where i call the Judul() to be shown when they return the text

```
Card(
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Flexible(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                        child: Text(
                                          Judul('value')
                                        )
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 10.0,
                                      ),
                                      Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                        child: Text(
                                          '12',
                                          maxLines: 2,
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.green,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
```

I cut the other part since it cant fit the StackOverflow reuirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whenever the TextField changes you have to set the state of the regular text to whatever the TextField is so that it can pass it to the judul function like this

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  String formText = '';


  judul(String value) {
    if (value == '1') {
      return 'one';
    } else if (value == '2') {
      return 'two';
    } else if (value == '3') {
      return 'Three';
    } else if (value == '4') {
      return 'Four';
    } else if (value == '5') {
      return 'Five';
    } else if (value == '6') {
      return 'Six';
    } else if (value == '7') {
      return 'Seven';
    } else {
      return 'null';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(judul(formText)),
        TextFormField(
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              formText = value;
            });
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Macchiato is this what your trying to do

Comment: yes, but i do change some of the code, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The `judul()` function is not returning any `value`; So you will have to do like below:

```
String Judul(String value) {
  if (value == '1') {
    print('one');
  } else if (value == '2') {
    print('two');
  } else if (value == '3) {
    print('Three');
  } else if (value == '4') {
    print('Four');
  } else if (value == '5') {
    print('Five');
  } else if (value == '6') {
    print('Six');
  } else if (value == '7') {
    print('Seven');
  } else (value){
    print('null');
  };
  return value;
}
```

Comment: it fixed the error issue but why the Text widget didn't show the print result?

Comment: You will have to call ```setState((){})``` rebuild the changes

Answer (score 0):

I happened because of you provide null string in Text Widget.
So you should try like this

```
    Judul(String value) {
  if (value == '1') {
    print('one');
  } else if (value == '2') {
    print('two');
  } else if (value == '3) {
    print('Three');
  } else if (value == '4') {
    print('Four');
  } else if (value == '5') {
    print('Five');
  } else if (value == '6') {
    print('Six');
  } else if (value == '7') {
    print('Seven');
  } else (value){
    print('null');
  };
  return " ";
}
```

Comment: it fixed the error issue but why the Text widget didn't show the print result?

Comment: because you does not return any value if you want show something in Text widget your should replace print into "return value;" something like this

Comment: Bescause you will have to rebuld the widget to show the latest value. to do so, You will have to call ```setState((){});```

Comment: @GourangoSutradhar should i change text widget? or modified it?

Comment: You will have to rebuild the widget. I will have to see your full class to provide the specific changes.

Comment: @GourangoSutradhar stackoverflow doesnt allow me to share the full code since it says too many code, I would like to provide you the Text widget Part

Comment: @Macchiato if your not actually ever planning on changing the text after the first time you dont need to set state only if your trying to change the value of the Text from what it was before do you need to set state

Comment: @Apb yes it will change again and again following to the TextFormField